# Permgen space error tomcat

Tags: java, memory, tomcat

I just installed two tomcat in my machine and deployed same application on both. Both application and tomcats are running great. Now i tried adding both the services to services.msc. I done this successfully. Now i can start and stop any service from services.msc. But on accessing both application simultaneously, i found, i am able to access only one application and when i am trying to access other application, the corresponding service goes stop with a permgen space error in the logs.

I tried increasing space of ms and mx and also i found that "Path to executable" under tomcat6w.exe is same.

Now my concern is how to remove that permgen space error. In my points it looks that both services are using one tomcat.

**if i am starting tomcats through command prompt or through batch file both are working great but problem causes only on the case when i am accessing both services from services.msc.**

Can you guys please help me in overcoming this problem.

Comment: Have you looked/followed the manual, http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/windows-service-howto.html ? Did you run Tomcat6w //ES to edit service properties?

Answer (score 1):

Set `XX:MaxPermSize`. It will increase the PermSize of your JVM. For example `-XX:MaxPermSize=64m`. [Reference](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/vmoptions-jsp-140102.html)

Comment: As described i tried this. Infact application on both the tomcats is running fine when tomcats are started from batch files but problem arises when tomcats are started from windows services.msc

Comment: @Kuri - you didn't say anything about the permsize. You said ms and mx (actualy Xmx and Xms). Which are about the heap size, not about the perm size.